# search and echo multiple results out mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

Sorry if it's a stupid question but i really can't find a answer :)

Can i search and echo multiple results out of my database? for example

```
id|first name|last name|email-adress

1 |matthias  |oben     |matthiasoben@...
2 |senne     |vanhoof  |sennevanhoof@...
3 |han       |jacobs   |hanjacobs@...
4 |matthias  |dieltiens|matthiasdieltiens...
5 |jeroen    |meys     |jeroen.meys@...
```

and i want to echo the email-adress of the peoples with the
name 'matthias'

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like ....

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM People WHERE first_name = 'matthias'";

$results = mysql_query($query);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['email'] . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, u should run mysql_query, and then do loop until the mysql_fetch_row is empty:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from bla");
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
your code here... $row[0]...$row[FIELD NUBMER];
}
```

for you seconds question, you should use WHERE in ur query

```
SELECT 'email' FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE name='matthias'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use an SQL statement that returns multiple rows, for example

```
SELECT `email-address` FROM `table` WHERE `first name` = 'matthias'
```

(some very bad column names there; stick to letters, numbers and underscores only)